# Snippet Description is not displayed in Google Plus Post (Android)

Tags: android, share, google-plus, posting, field-description

I used following code to share post on google plus in android app. But It does not shows description of snippet.It shows everything except description.Is there any reason of this?

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
            .setText("Test")
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setContentDeepLinkId(
                    "Example",  /** Deep-link identifier */
                    "Snippet",  /** Snippet title */

     // ------------ Below Desciption is not visible in post --------------

                    "Good Example", /** Snippet description */

                    Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/snippet.png"))
            .getIntent();
    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, POST_ON_GOOGLE_PLUS);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have enabled deep linking in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) under `Client ID for installed applications`.

If that is enabled for your Android client, try and see if the sample code from the documentation works, I just tested it and it works for me:

```
    PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this, mPlusClient)
    .setText("Lemon Cheesecake recipe")
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setContentDeepLinkId("/cheesecake/lemon", /** Deep-link identifier */
            "Lemon Cheesecake recipe", /** Snippet title */
            "A tasty recipe for making lemon cheesecake.", /** Snippet description */
            Uri.parse("http://example.com/static/lemon_cheesecake.png"))
     .getIntent();
```

Something to note:

- `PlusShare.Builder(this)` will use an unauthorized client and will fallback to a regular share.

If you don't pass the client the following will not work:

- Prefilling recipients
- Specifying the snippet
- Setting the call to action button

I'm guessing this is why the interactive post is not rendering correctly for you. Make sure to pass your authorized API client.

Comment: Yes,I have deeolinking enabled in Google Plus API Console .I have tried with this,only change when i tries with this code is that I have PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this) in place of PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this, mPlusClient) .So is there any difference between these two?

Comment: I don't know, I will see what I can figure out.

Comment: Ok.Let me know when you come up with solution.

Comment: Again, does the sample code I put up there work? If not, the problem is not the section of code where you are creating the sharebuilder.

Comment: Just tested again and figured out the difference between Builder(this) vs Builder(this, mPlusClient)

Comment: No,Builder(this) and Builder(this, mPlusClient) gives me same result.